# Get JSON values from Webview

Tags: ios, swift

How can I find Json response value from WebView 
Example: There is a one Login URL and we are opening this in Webview use of this we will get token and I want to add this token in user default.

Answer (score 0):

Store your JSON data in a hidden field as a string in your html file.

```
<input id="TokenInfo" type="hidden" value="YOUR_JSON_DATA"/>
```

Add following javaScript Code into your html page.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var tokenInfo = $("#TokenInfo").val();
        try {
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.scriptHandler.postMessage(tokenInfo); // For iOS
        } catch (e) {
            //
        } 
        try {
            Android.login(tokenInfo); // For Android
        } catch (e) {
            //
        }
    })
</script>
```

From android end you need to add a JavaScriptInterface interface into to web view

```
final JavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(getContext());
webview.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "Android");

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void login(String tokenInfo) {
        // deserialize your json here.
    }
}
```